# Image button like spinner

Tags: android

I am looking to have a image button which acts like a spinner in XML. I have found some information on this but nothing like what am after. So when i click a image view a spinner will appear with a list to choose from that will come from my DB if passable. What i found which didn't do anything

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/KeUxBt4SJLw

I want to be able to have 10 image buttons in my activity which have a spinner for each one.
And when the users pick from the spinner list a dialog will appear(which i will try later hopefully after i can code this first).

Any help will help thanks

```
      package com.spinn;

      import android.app.Activity;
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
      import android.widget.Button;
      import android.widget.Spinner;

      public class MainActivity extends Activity {

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
      this, R.array.array_name, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
      adapter.setDropDownViewResource(             
      android.R.layout.    simple_spinner_dropdown_item );

        Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.unique_id );
        s.setAdapter( adapter );
```

XML

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/unique_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/c3" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using spinners with setting their background your image buttons' background? This should do the trick...

Comment: I did try this but it did nothing